# Store the data from Materialized Views

Tags: oracle11g, materialized-views

I have a materialized view(MV) which will refresh everyday at 23:00. It will select from a large transaction table (e.g. 100 million of records) and summarize the data which to be used in reporting purposes.

The MV is very simple just contain 4 columns and 7 records. Each time when user generate the report, it will always show the data as in the MV. Now user request to be able to view back the data of last year. Due to my MV always replace existing data, I am not able to achieve the user request.

My question
 1. Is it possible to store the data in MV automatically in a persistent table?
 2. Is it feasible to create a trigger to insert the data in MV to another table each time the MV is refresh complete?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Materialized View does not have a trigger. If the requirement is to have historical data, why not consider having a standard transactional table to have data persistence using a Stored Procedure which is possible to execute using scheduler jobs.

Comment: Hi @Jåcob, thank you very much for the clarification. I will go by this direction. Can you please answer this question so that I can mark this as correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Materialised Views do not have triggers. However, Updatable Materialized View does have triggers but it has a catch to it, it must be based upon a single table.

**Based on more than one table**

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON EMP;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_test
   REFRESH FAST WITH PRIMARY KEY
   FOR UPDATE
AS
   SELECT *
     FROM emp em JOIN DEPT de ON EM.DEPTNO = DE.DEPTNO;
```

> ORA-12013: updatable materialized views must be simple enough to do fast refresh

**Based on single table**

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_test
   REFRESH FAST WITH PRIMARY KEY
   FOR UPDATE
AS
   SELECT * FROM emp;

Materialized View created.
```

Trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_tg
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF ENAME, MGR
   ON MV_TEST
   REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   tmpVar   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   tmpVar := 0;


   NULL;
    -- do as per the logic
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      NULL;
      -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
      RAISE;
END test_tg;

Trigger created.
```

If the requirement is to have historical data, why not consider a standard transactional table to have data persistence using a Stored Procedure which is possible to execute using scheduler jobs.

As you have cited querying a large table which has 100 million records, my reckoning would be to use `FOLL ALL` or `BULK COLLECT` or consider batch processing, needless to say; this is a different topic.

The below are pseudo codes for procedure and scheduler jobs, make changes as deemed necessary. Either use INSERT or MERGE

**Procedure using INSERT**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE historical_records (p_emp_no emp.empno%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN
   FOR rec IN (  SELECT ename, mgr, SUM (sal) tot_sal
                   FROM scott.emp
                  WHERE empno = p_emp_no
               GROUP BY ename, mgr)
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO hist_table (empno,
                              ename,
                              mgr,
                              sal_tot)
           VALUES (rec.empno,
                   rec.ename,
                   rec.mgr,
                   rec.tot_sal);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

**Procedure using MERGE**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE historical_records (p_emp_no emp.empno%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN
   MERGE INTO hist_table trg
        USING (  SELECT ename, mgr, SUM (sal) tot_sal
                   FROM scott.emp
                  WHERE empno = p_emp_no
               GROUP BY ename, mgr) src
           ON (trg.empno = src.empno)
   WHEN MATCHED
   THEN
      UPDATE SET trg.ename = src.ename, trg.mgr = src.mgr
   WHEN NOT MATCHED
   THEN
      INSERT     (trg.empno, trg.ename, trg.sal_tot)
          VALUES (src.empno, src.ename, src.tot_sal);
END;
```

**Scheduler Job**

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
      job_name          => 'HIST_PROC_JOB',
      job_type          => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
      JOB_ACTION        => 'BEGIN historical_records; END;',
      start_date        => SYSDATE,
      repeat_interval   => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=23;BYMINUTE=05',
      end_date          => NULL,
      enabled           => TRUE,
      comments          => 'Historical data insertion');
END;
/
```